# How to convert Multiple columns to multiple rows in powershell?

Tags: powershell, csv, multiple-columns, rows

Basically i have input.csv file with mutiple columns it has to convert to mutiple rows..

`input.csv`:

```
Month,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec

and i want to add extra columns to csv file
```

```
i have a problem here..my entire input file changed,and now from jan to dec..i have these in 2nd row ,like
```

sample.csv

```
"Application","Entity","Project","Years","Version","Currency","Scenario","LineItem","Account","Period"
```

"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"

"App - NA","11002","Project - NA","FY22","Working","USD","Budget","No Line Item","640605",171.40,171.80,170.50,169.10,178.60,168.00,167.80,167.70,179.40,176.70,176.70,177.10

but i want output.csv..like

"Application","Entity","Project","Years","Version","Currency","Scenario","LineItem","Account","Period","Data"

"App - NA","11002","Project - NA","FY22","Working","USD","Budget","No Line Item","640605",Jan, 171.40 "App - NA","11002","Project - NA","FY22","Working","USD","Budget","No Line Item","640605",Feb,171.80

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need to unpivot some columns. This worked for me:

```
Function UnPivot-Object {
    [CmdletBinding()][OutputType([Object[]])]Param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeLine = $True)]$InputObject
    )
    Process {
        $Properties = $InputObject.PSObject.Properties
        $Row = ($Properties | Select-Object -First 1).Value
        $Properties | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object {
            [PSCustomObject]@{Row = $Row; Column = $_.Name; Value = $_.Value}
        }
    }
}; Set-Alias UnPivot UnPivot-Object
```

As for adding new columns, try this:

```
foreach ($row in $csv)
{
    $data = Get-DataFromSomewhere -Id $row.Id

    $row | Add-Member -Name 'first_name' -Value $data.FirstName -MemberType NoteProperty
    $row | Add-Member -Name 'last_name' -Value $data.LastName -MemberType NoteProperty
}
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: i have a problem here..my entire input file changed,and now from jan to dec..i have these in 2nd rwo,like

Comment: Looks like you hit enter before typing all the question. Try explaining the issue again